# How to get incremental value in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to get incremented value only while extracting data from Table. Below is my code snippet.

```
public interface Repo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T,T> {

 @Query("Select new CustomObject(name, phone, place) from table")
  List<CustomObjectDTO> getData();

}
```

Note:   `CustomObjectDTO` has all three attributes mentioned in select query.

May I know please How can I get the `incrementalID` as first col in select query ? I mean need a serial number with every record in select query output.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you quickly update the question and put the table behind CustomObject? also is incrementalID a primary key?

Comment: @JuliyanageSilva CustomObject is not a entity but a DTO. So am just reading data from table and putting in DTO. That's all

Comment: @Carol Do you mean that your table has no incremental ID, but you want to add a generated one to the DTOs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be this:

```
 @Query("Select new CustomObject(incremantal_column_name,name, phone, place) from table")
 List<CustomObjectDTO> getData();
```

and in CustomObjectDTO class:

@Column(name = "incremantal_column_name)
long incrementalID;

Comment: Dont have incrementalID col in table. But need incremented val in select query.

Comment: I edited the answer, please have a look